# SQLalchemy empty column definition model

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've sqlalchemy models like below:

```
class table1(db.Model):
item_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
campaign = Column(Integer)


class table2(db.Model):
item_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
campaign = Empty
```

In table1 I've campaign value, but in second it's not available. How can I declare an empty column?

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need to specify a value for each column when inserting a new row in a database, unless the column does not allow for any empty cells (meaning it can't be `NULL`). If you don't have any value to add in the column when inserting the row, you can simply specify the column to be `nullable`. Now the value will be set to `NULL` if no value was given.

```py
class SomeModel(db.Model):
    item_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    campaign = Column(Integer, nullable=True)
```